# Ubuntu 18.04 installed on 4 computers, shotwell doesn't work right on one of them

Tags: nautilus, shotwell

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on 4 computers, identical installation on each of them.  But on one of them when I try to display a photo using Shotwell, by clicking on a file name in a nautilus window, it doesn't display the photo, but shows a library display.  I have never set up a library, so what's going on?  I have removed Shotwell, and reinstalled it, several times, and I get the same thing every time.  I figure there must be a configuration file somewhere causing this, but I can't find it.  If I invoke Shotwell via command line, like "shotwell photo.jpg", it displays the photo correctly.  Note that it also works fine on the other three, identically configured computers.

Comment: what if you do sudo apt remove --purge shotwell && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt install shotwell ?

Comment: Already tried that.  Tried it again just now.  Same result.  Have tried removing it through synaptic and the software installer and reinstalling it, but I get the same result.  If I try to display a photo by clicking on it in nautilus, I get the library instead.  If I invoke it through a command line, it displays the image, just as it should.

Comment: I've come up with what I think is a crude but usable workaround.  I've built a one-line script containing the command "shotwell $1" and put it in with nautilus scripts, and that works for me without seriously disrupting my workflow.  But I really do wish I could get the real problem corrected.